# Programmatically logging in not working

Tags: members, login

Context: In this situation, I cannot use the template tag {exp:member:login_form}.

I'm trying to parse the information sent via POST to login a member to the site.

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
$this->EE->load->library('session');
$this->EE->load->library('auth');

$return = "..."; // This variable is set somewhere else and is not an issue

// DEBUG A: print_r($this->EE->session->userdata);

if(!!$this->EE->session->userdata["username"]) {

    // Member is already logged in
    $this->EE->functions->redirect($return);

} else {

    // Member is trying to log in
    $username = $this->input->post("username", true);
    $password = $this->input->post("password", true);

    $session = $this->EE->auth->authenticate_username($username, $password);

    if(!$session){

        // Error handling here

    } else {

        // Member authenticated. Redirects.
        $session->start_session();
        $session->remember_me();

        // DEBUG B: print_r($this->EE->session->userdata);

        $this->functions->redirect($return);

    }
}
```

I confirm that a session is created in the database when `$session->start_session()` is called. Cookies are also present in the browser.

If I uncomment `DEBUG B`, I can see that the `$this->EE->session->userdata` array is filled with correct info. If I uncomment `DEBUG A` and revisit the page, `$this->EE->session->userdata` does not recognized the user I'm logged as. It seems the session does not persists. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could it be that you're using EE core? I'm having a similar issue using core but I need to verify this using my paid version of EE. Either way, did you end up resolving your problem?

Comment: I was using a full version of EE. Sadly, I ended up using a third-party plugin: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/authenticate.